# RevMob iPad issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, revmob

So I am implementing RevMob to my app and it works fine on my iPhone. My app consists of tableview and other views connected to it. It launches and there's a banner, as there should be, and I tap a cell to go to another view and it works but then when I go back it crashes. Here's the output throughout this operation:

```
2013-09-26 00:07:28.027 iConvertMaster[890:60b] [RevMob] Starting RevMobAds  
2013-09-26 00:07:28.580 iConvertMaster[890:60b] [RevMob] Initializating Banner.  
2013-09-26 00:07:28.635 iConvertMaster[890:60b] [RevMob] Requesting banner data.  
2013-09-26 00:07:29.726 iConvertMaster[890:60b] [RevMob] Ad received: (200).  
2013-09-26 00:07:31.667 iConvertMaster[890:60b] [RevMob] Banner did received.  
2013-09-26 00:07:31.668 iConvertMaster[890:60b] -[__NSCFArray setStatus:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e6dc10  
2013-09-26 00:07:31.669 iConvertMaster[890:60b] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> -[__NSCFArray setStatus:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e6dc10  
2013-09-26 00:07:31.869 iConvertMaster[890:60b] [RevMob] Initializating Banner.  
2013-09-26 00:07:31.871 iConvertMaster[890:60b] [RevMob] Requesting banner data.  
2013-09-26 00:07:31.957 iConvertMaster[890:60b] [RevMob] Initializating Banner.  
2013-09-26 00:07:31.958 iConvertMaster[890:60b] [RevMob] Requesting banner data.  
2013-09-26 00:07:32.160 iConvertMaster[890:60b] [RevMob] Ad received: (200).  
2013-09-26 00:07:32.246 iConvertMaster[890:60b] [RevMob] Banner did received.  
(lldb)
```

The weird thing is there's no output at the time of the crash, only this exception:
`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x9be4a6e`

Comment: Can you add more details? Like the code to add the banner

Comment: @diogot Actually I have already fixed this by contacting RevMob support directly. Just for completion, I was using `showBanner` and `hideBanner` methods when I should have been using the `RevMobBanner` and `RevMobBannerView` classes in the first place. Anyways thanks for your interest!

Comment: @YoussefSami how to fixed this issue ? please tell me .